How do I wirelessly access a locally hosted Node.js server?
I'm following the instructions on this link to setup the node.js server, but I'm not really sure about how to make it so that the server is accessible over a locally created Wi-Fi. I want other devices to be able to access the server wirelessly to run through some testing. Could someone give me some directions as to how to approach this?

What I see people doing with node local apps is to use a reverse proxy running on the node server, that will take requests, proxy them to localhost, and reply with responses. you cannot (even with a local hotspot or whatever) allow another host to access localhost. perhaps this has some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408142/how-to-use-node-on-localhost-with-nginx-reverse-proxy

how would you do it "wired" ... why would it be different "wireless"?

@JaromandaX I don't know, I've never done that. All I've done is run the server on my desktop. I've never tried accessing the server with another device through a wired connection or wirelessly. I assume it would be very similar both ways, could you explain how I could do that?
